# По разному считается (отображается?) репа в профиле и др. местах

Tags: дефект, репутация, профиль-участника

Получил -2. А репа упала на -102. Причем в профиле, на графике, все правильно - 177, а предыдущий отсчет — 177. В профиле же, в исторической справке, тоже всего -2 фигурирует последней (первой) строкой, но там же итог — 77. И везде в остальных местах отображается 77.

Значит что-то где-то неправильно считается. Или репа была снята на сотку, но не везде это отобразилось, или же — наоборот.

**ADD:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

[Ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807067/178988) удалён как **Невежливый или оскорбительный** - удаление с этой причиной (а также с причиной **Спам**) приводит к штрафу в 100 баллов. Вроде бы это должно показываться [в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217260/user6698332?tab=reputation)?

Comment: Я об этом не спрашивал. Я информаировал о нестыковке в данных. Но, спасибо и за эту наводку :) Вернемся к ней попозжа.

Comment: Добавл screenshot

Comment: @user6698332, внизу страницы есть флажок "показать удалённые сообщения" - если его отметить, что-то изменится?

Comment: Флажка не вижу. Есть "недавно удалённые ответы". Но там лишь тот ответ, который сегодня преобразовали в коммент. К этому не имеет отношения (вроде бы).

Comment: В каком разделе искать этот флажок: _"сводка, 
ответы, 
вопросы, 
метки, 
знаки, 
избранное, 
конкурсы, 
репутация, 
все действия, 
реакции, 
голоса"_? Да и при чем тут он, если **8сводка с графиком и итогом не бьют**...

Comment: @user6698332, в репутации - открой ссылку из моего ответа и промотай страницу вниз.

Comment: Нашел. Увидел. Но вопрос с графиком остается открытым... Там 177.

Comment: @user6698332, предположу, что число дней больше числа пикселей и ты просто физически не можешь увидеть этот скачок на графике и навести на него мышку.

Comment: Не знам. Но это не есть гуд. Да на графике видно (на скриине мышью закрыто) хвостик загибающийся вниз и зазор справа. Т.е. место есть. Прими куда-нибудь в баг-виш-лист. Я времени убил черти сколько, чтобы разобраться, пришлось вот людей дергать... А по поводу обстоятельств этой соточки уплывшей - куда, кому и где писать?

Comment: @user6698332 Попробуйте написать в форме ["Связаться с нами"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), которая в самом низу на любой странице.